# SQL function to return a value that contains an INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create a function that inserts a record and returns its primary key, so that I can pass that function as the parameter of another query. For example, I tried this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CreateEntity 
(
    @entityTypeId int,
    @siteId int
)
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @entityId bigint;

    INSERT INTO [ObjectSystem].[Entities] ([EntityTypeId], [SiteId], [Deleted])
    VALUES (@entityTypeId, @siteId, 0);

    SELECT @entityId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    RETURN @entityId;
END
GO
```

but MSSMS highlights the INSERT query and says "Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'Insert' within a function."

I'd like to be able to use such a function like so:

```
INSERT INTO OtherTable (EntityId, Name, Description) VALUES
(CreateEntity(), 'Test', 'This is a test item.'),
(CreateEntity(), 'Test', 'This is a test item.'),
(CreateEntity(), 'Test', 'This is a test item.'),
(CreateEntity(), 'Test', 'This is a test item.'),
(CreateEntity(), 'Test', 'This is a test item.'),
(CreateEntity(), 'Test', 'This is a test item.');
```

How can I achieve the desired effect, if at all? If it's not possible, what could I do that's similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this article : http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3348181/User-Defined-Functions-in-Microsoft-SQL-Server-2000.htm

> User Defined Functions cannot be used
>   to modify base table information. The
>   DML statements INSERT, UPDATE, and
>   DELETE cannot be used on base tables.

So you can't do an INSERT in a function.

Solution of article : [SQL Server Error Messages - Msg 443](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-443-insert.aspx)

Since the INSERT command is not allowed in a user-defined function, you have to use a stored procedure for this purpose instead.  Here’s the same script as the above function but using a stored procedure:

Answer (score 0):

DML query is not allowed in function in MS SQL. You can use that query in stored procedure and that should work.